# Obtaining Current Network Rate

Tags: c++, windows, crysis

I would like to obtain the current network transfer rate of download/upload. This is for a C++ gameserver DLL and the primary objective of this is to best predict the upper-latency limit to kick players from the server, when their latency is too high. 
Basically, a players' ping influences the fluency of their movements, and higher latency leads to more delayed movement, meaning that we need to get rid of the player if it becomes too high. This is to mainly keep players happy.

Via the internal functions of the gameserver I can get the internal process upload/download rates, but I cannot get Windows'.

I've looked pretty much everywhere, and have done so on-and-off for quite a few months. The only solutions I can find don't work, and the rest are specific to Linux.
The supported platforms (if it matters) are Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7. The compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013's default compiler.

***Edit***

Forgot to mention that my gameserver DLL will eventually be running on a dedicated server with no less than four IPs, so it needs to be able to measure the connection upload/download (at the current rate) for all the IPs collectively.

Comment: Are you allowed to use .net or only win-api?

Comment: I think so. I don't have access to the schematics, but I think the application *is* .net based. It is Crysis Wars Dedicated Server V1.5, and the server basically looks for a custom game DLL in `/Mods/[modname]/Bin[32 or 64]`. I'm currently using a multimedia library called SFML which allows me to have naive FTP functions. Not sure if this library covers inbound/outbound connection usage though.

Comment: Did you try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.speed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2 ?

Comment: No I haven't, since it only measures the speed of the networking interface, and not the actual amount of data currently going through.

Comment: Am I wrong? I looked at the solution in more detail and it `measures in bits per second`, but it also has `stats->OutputQueueLength`. Any idea what `stats->OutputQueueLength` does?

Comment: An Int64 value that specifies the total number of packets in the output queue. (according to: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipv4interfacestatistics.outputqueuelength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Throughput is more or less unrelated to latency. You probably want some other way to measure.

Comment: @fritzone So... am I right in saying that `stats->OutputQueueLength` is basically the amount of outgoing packets at that point in time?

Comment: @molbdnilo Good observation, I guess I should have added the reason behind this in the first post. Basically, if we have a set latency limit, and the dedicated server is busy updating/downloading, we can increase the latency limit so that players do not get kicked. Obviously we can do this the other way round, that we can detect potential DoS attacks, then automatically null-route the current server IP and then change to a different one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a GUI application that offers the same functionality:

[image: GUI Application]

[GUI Application Source](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6259/Monitoring-network-speed)

I guess that I should be able to extract the necessary libraries from this project, then use them in my own project.
As my IPs all use the same 1GBPS network interface, it should be able to work to my requirements fine.